# How do I have multiple actions performed with an ActionListener in java?

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, actionlistener

I'm writing a program right now that involves two JButtons. The class that contains these JButtons implements ActionListener and therefore contains the method ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e). Is there anyway to have these JButtons both do unique actions within the same ActionPerformed method?

Comment: Yes, but it is often better to add a listener (or `Action`) for each control.  See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can distinguish them in the following way:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object src = e.getSource();

  if (src == bt1) {
    // do actions for bt1;
  }
  else if (src == b2) {
   // do action for bt2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the source of your actionEvent with `e.getSource()`. Then just compare that source with your buttons and do the specific action if they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Compare the `source` of the `ActionEvent` object to see which button the event came from (i.e., call `getSource()`) and then act accordingly.